# Generate ipa without apple developer account in Xcode 11

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipa, xcode11

I searched a lot on this topic and tried to create ipa using this link  https://medium.com/m%CE%BBgn%CE%BEt%CE%BBr/how-to-export-a-ipa-file-from-xcode-without-a-dev-account-bac8b2645ad3

I do every single step till Step 4 - 4 point but in point 5 which Change “Any iOS SDK” from “iOS Developer” to “Ad Hoc Code Sign,” for both “Debug” and “Release.” I am unable to find the Ad Hoc Code Sign Option. For Automatic Settings, options available to me are as follows:

1. Apple Development
2. Apple Distribution
3. Ios developer
4. Ios distribution

   this is both for debud and release modes. ALso if there is any other way of doing this, pointers to that will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve @sver?

Comment: No. or I would have posted the solution here. :)

Comment: You can post to the answer ^^ And I will be vote it.